# Is a usecase document required for security review?

Tags: managed-package, security-review

We plan to submit our managed package for security review. We do not have a usecase document for the app. Do we need to provide it for the security review? If yes, do we need to document the basic usecases or a thorough list of all usecases for the app?

Answer (score 1):

At least the last time I was part of an ISV, yes, this document is required and you cannot proceed without it. Each element in your package simply needs a brief description of what it does. For example, Visualforce Page ABC might be a screen to capture credit card details, and Apex Class ABCController would be the controller for that page. You don't need to be super-descriptive, just enough to give an idea of what each element does (in our docs, each component was described by a simple one sentence description). This is probably the minimum amount of documentation you should have for your app anyways.

Comment: Agreed with @sfdcfox. A good reference point can be found at https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Security_Review_Test_Info#3._Documentation

As a side note, I would also encourage you to run a free scan of your application beforehand: https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner & be prepared to write up a false positives document if the scanner calls out anything that you believe does not need to be fixed.